# Combine data in multiple rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle12c

I have Oracle 12c so please answer my question based on using Oracle syntax. I want to combine data in multiple rows into 1 row. Please see expected result for an example.I tried using PIVOT function but it did not work for me because I want to PIVOT Call_day from previous row to latest row and want to have list of columns as shown in "Expected result" below. Thank you for your help.

Data in the table:

```
Acct_num  Call_day    Call_code Start_day_To_Call
1         04/23/2018  AA        04/02/2018
1         04/24/2018  NULL      04/02/2018
1         04/25/2018  CC        04/02/2018
2         04/26/2018  ZZ        05/02/2018
2         04/27/2018  CC        05/02/2018
```

If multiple calls made within Start_day_To_Call date then I want last 2 latest call pivot data as shown below:

Expected result:

```
Acct_num  Call_day1   Call_day2    Call_code1  Call_code2  Start_day_To_Call       
1         04/24/2018  04/25/2018   NULL        CC          04/02/2018        
2         04/26/2018  04/27/2018   ZZ          CC          05/02/2018
```

Comment: please correct the format of the data in your question, use help at the lower right corner of the editing box for clues

Answer (score 0):

If you want only two days you can use this query:

first you get last call for each acct_num and then find previous call and then fill data according to them. You can use an id to touch performance if needed.

```
select p.acct_num,
   p.prev_last_day,
   (select z.call_code
      from test_tbl z
     where z.acct_num = p.acct_num
       and z.call_day = p.prev_last_day) prev_call_code,
   last_day,
   (select z.call_code
      from test_tbl z
     where z.acct_num = p.acct_num
       and z.call_day = p.last_day) last_call_code,
   p.start_day_to_call
from (select x.acct_num,
           max(x.call_day) last_day,
           max((select max(y.call_day)
                 from test_tbl y
                where y.acct_num = x.acct_num
                  and y.call_day < x.call_day)) prev_last_day,
           min(x.start_day_to_call) start_day_to_call
      from test_tbl x
     group by x.acct_num) p
order by p.acct_num
```